# Azure AD permissions for app only token

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365api

I need to create a service which gets messages from specific office 365 mail box user100@atenant.onmicrosoft.com/.
My understanding is that in this case I need to specify required permissions in application registration for my app in the Azure management portal for Microsoft Azure Active Directory.
Is it possible to provide mail.read permission to the particular account instead of mail.read.all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No , you need to write your own code in app to restrict access to particular account , and you should grant mail.read.all application permission which allows the app to read mail in all mailboxes without a signed-in user.

And if you only wants to read emails from particular account in a service , you could try delegate permission with mail.read and use the [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/).

Comment: First option is undesirable as it requires Azire AD to provide read all permissions for user mailboxes.

Comment: Then you could try resource owner flow with delegate permission

Comment: Sorry the messaging was sent partially.  First option is undesirable as it requires Azire AD to provide read all permissions for user mailboxes.  The second option looks viable.  I am assuming in this case  service can directly call   the user specific mail box and at azure AD as well the access is only given for specific user

Comment: With option 2,  the service app could access the specific one user's own mailbox , others can't access . Or you could create a shared mailbox , and grant Mail.Read.Shared delegate permission which allows the app to read mail that the user can access, including the user's own and shared mail.